# Как правильно реализовать функцию functional с функцией fstream

Tags: c++

Не могу разобраться с подключением foo и foo2
Я бы хотел реализовать отдельные функции чтения и запись что бы я мог создавать их.
Не обращайте внимания что там используется ofstream вместо fstream это просто тест.

```
#include <functional>    
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;    

class H
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "test" << endl;
        out.write((char*)& y, sizeof(y));
    }
    void foo2()
    {
        cout << "test2" << endl;
        out.read((char*)& y, sizeof(y));
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void openwriteclose(ofstream& out, T1 y, T2 d, function<void()> n)
    {
        out.open(d, ofstream::app);
        n();
        out.close();
    }
};

class S : public H
{
public:

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    S(T1 y, T2 d)
    {
        ofstream out;
        openwriteclose<T1, T2>(out, y, d, foo);
    }
};


void main()
{
   S(777, "3.bin");
}
```

Comment: А Вам точно нужны шаблоны? Ваш код содержит просто кучу ошибок. К примеру, `void main` или переменная y, которая не объявлена в foo.

Comment: void main это не ошибка, а вот что касается foo там да есть ошибка и я пока не знаю как ее решить, надо как то вызывать функцию внутри за пределами класса

out.write не работает за пределами в этом проблема.

Что касается шаблона да он мне нужен

Comment: я правильно понимаю что это полиморфизм